# Trapezoid with rounded corners works in Chrome but can't get it done in firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

#### HTML

```
<div class="trapezoid"></div>
```

Here's my code it works on chrome, but not on firefox. Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

#### CSS

```
.trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 370px solid #19313b;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    width: 1145px;
    margin-top:50px
    margin-left: 80px;
    border-radius: 83px 83px 0 0 / 285px 285px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWWEjb I don't see differences between chrome and firefox

Comment: @fcalderan 
sorry, forgot to remove height property, now it gets rounded corners in chrome